# Strings in Sparql

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I'm playing around with [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/).

With this query I get all people who were born in London:

```
SELECT ?person
WHERE {      
  ?person dbo:birthPlace :London
}
```

But why I get an empty result when I execute this query?

```
SELECT ?person
WHERE {      
  ?person dbo:birthPlace "London"
}
```

I just changed `London` to a String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the object of this relation is an entity, and not a string, hence the absence of result with the second query.

To know if a property (i.e dbo:birthPlace) relates an entity to a literal or not, one approach is to have a look at the "About" page of the property, for example, [birthPlace's one](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace).

What can be seen there is that the type of birthPlace is **owl:ObjectProperty**, meaning that the object of the relation will have to be an entity, defined with a **URI**. 
The other possibility would be **DatatypeProperty**, [as for the "abstract" property for example](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract), where the object of the relation will be a literal.

The fact that the birth place is an entity allows a lot of things, such as retrieving specific information about that place in the same query, for example.

Hope that helps !